# Logs not working inside AuthController

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, logging

I am trying to log Auth activity using Laravel 5.2 built-in Logs API.

The code would be like

```
\Log::info("Message here");
```

It works inside HomeController. However, it does not work inside AuthController.

Sample code inside logout method:

```
public function getLogout()
{
    \Log::info('User has logged out.', ['email' => \Auth::user()->email]);
    \Auth::logout();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Just tested on a fresh install the string was logged. Run composer dump-autoload, maybe will do.

Comment: it's working on everywhere,i just tested now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Route::auth()` to register your Auth related routes, it does not use that method, `getLogout`. It uses `logout`.

Check your routes with `php artisan route:list` to see what controller methods those Auth routes are using.

Comment: The route was using Auth\AuthController@logout. I set it to Auth\AuthController@getLogout and it started working!

Thanks! I feel so stupid to have had missed that!

Comment: nah, believe me a lot of people end up trying to override the `get...` and `post...` versions of those methods. I hope they are removed in 5.3 to remove this confusion :)

Comment: Laravel claims another victim. :P